# I wrote a code to animate badge when the user click on a button, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this

hover the animation: `animated slideIn` doesn't trigger, while the console show notihing

```
let getAddToCart = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');
let getCartBadge = document.querySelector('.cartBadge');

getAddToCart.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('clicked');

    // animate the cartBadge
    getCartBadge.classList.add('animated', 'slideIn');

    // other stuff
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't add multiple classes as you did. You should do `.add('animated', 'slideIn')` or do the `add` separately for each class.

Comment: I think I have a problem with the foreach, even by showing console.log, its not working, also I have edited the snipper

Comment: You need to share a minimal reproducible example of your current work to allow us to help you on this case.

Comment: its a long codebase, wondering why the console show nothing, in my case, the message: `clicked`

Comment: Well, I can't tell if anything goes wrong here to cause this behaviour. For that reason, I asked for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also keep in mind  iterating over the product of `querySelectorAll` directly, is not a good practice because it will generate an array-like element and not the actual array element, so you need to create an array from its product like: `Array.from(getAddToCart)`

Comment: @Cheerio can not be cache? console.logs update?

Comment: @SMAKSS its a long codebase, now i just want to show the message in the console,

Comment: What are the `item`s? Are you clicking them to actually fire the listeners? As already suggested several times, you need to create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you mention the code is long, but likely 99% of it is not relevant to this problem.  Your task is to create a *small* snippet of HTML/JS which reproduces this problem, and nothing else, by removing all other code not related to exactly these few lines of JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a class name with space in it. Try adding them with two statements, or use `animated-slideIn`.

Comment: even, I think the problem is with the foreach

Answer (score 0):

**This is a guess:** You checked the scope inside your event listener? Try select getCartBadge using a variable self in external scope:

```
let getAddToCart = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');
let getCartBadge = document.querySelector('.cartBadge');
let self = this;

getAddToCart.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    self.getCartBadge.classList.add('animated', 'slideIn');
  });
});
```

or using arrow function:

```
let getAddToCart = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');
let getCartBadge = document.querySelector('.cartBadge');

getAddToCart.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getCartBadge.classList.add('animated', 'slideIn');
  });
});
```

See more about scopes in:
https://www.programiz.com/javascript/variable-scope
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

---

Shortened version if you want to explore:

```
const getAddToCart = document.querySelectorAll('.addToCart');
const getCartBadge = document.querySelector('.cartBadge');

getAddToCart.forEach(item => {
    item.onclick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        getCartBadge.classList.add('animated', 'slideIn');
    }
});
```

Comment: i think there is double });

Comment: still nothing in console,

Comment: Try insert a **debugger** after select getCartBadge and getAddToCart. See if you are selecting them correctly. If yes, you can check step to step for find the problem.

Comment: I believe there is no problem with the scoping in the OP and trying to use `this` keyword is completely unnecessary in this case. Also, the `onclick` approach is not a shorthand for the `addEventListener` one and it is called inline event handling which has some drawbacks in comparison to `addEventListener`.

Comment: first const return `NodeList []`, the second return the html tag of the badge

Comment: @SMAKSS `console.log(getAddToCart);` returned `NodeList []`

Comment: that's the problem, there are no elements to loop, check your elements addToCart exist your page in the moment/state.

Comment: @Cheerio It means it couldn't find any element with `addToCart` class on it and the `querySelectorAll` has returned an empty list.

Comment: @SMAKSS about your response: we can't say for sure about the scope problem, we would need to see the entire code, so it was just a guess.

thanks for explaining about the difference between on click and addEventListener =]

Comment: @SMAKSS thank you, now I see the animation but only one time, when clicking on other button `add to cart`, no animation is triggered

Comment: I should remove the animation with setTimeout :)